# MySQL Regular expression for search

Tags: mysql, null, substring

I have two tables in MySQL, one of products, and other of exclusions. I have to select all products in table `products` which are not present in the table `exclusions`. I have succeeded when the exclusion is made through a "direct" field equivalence, namely, the reference code of the product.

But many products can be excluded through a pattern. It consists of the 3 last digits of the reference code. So, if I have the value "++6", it means that the third digit of that sequence, i.e., the last digit of the reference code, must be different to 6. If it is 6, then the product is excluded. It is here where I am stuck. What regular expression or something should I use?
The pattern could perfectly be '0+6', '036', etc.

I paste the structure and data of the example tables, and the SELECT which works with the reference. The problem is to alter the SELECT to include those regular expression (or whatever) that can account for the exclusion with "pattern".

```
 CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `exclusions` (
   `id_exclusions` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `reference` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   `pattern` varchar(3) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_exclusions`)
  ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=3 ;

 INSERT INTO `exclusions` (`id_exclusions`, `reference`, `pattern`) VALUES
 (1, '8036', ''),
 (2, '', '++5');

  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
   `id_products` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `reference` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id_products`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=4 ;

 INSERT INTO `products` (`id_products`, `reference`) VALUES
     (1, '8034'),
     (2, '8035'),
      (3, '8036');
```

Now the SELECT code currently working

```
SELECT * FROM products AS p LEFT JOIN exclusions AS e ON p.reference = e.reference WHERE e.reference IS NULL
```

Result:

```
  id_products, reference, id_exclusions, reference, pattern
  1, 8034, NULL, NULL, NULL
  2, 8035, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

With the corrected SELECT, it should only return

```
  id_products, reference, id_exclusions, reference, pattern
  1, 8034, NULL, NULL, NULL
```

as the 'xx5' reference code is excluded.

Comment: The Result is OK !!. you have 3 rows in the table products and only **one** match with the reference (8036) so you get the two other rows if exclude the match **"WHERE e.reference IS NULL"**

Comment: How long are your product codes? Does it need to account for any arbitrary length of the string? Do you need to convert your xx5 into a regex in mysql or can you do it in the backend?

Comment: can you please post more samples what the output is with your table with different data

Comment: The product codes are 10 digits long, constant length. I am trying with SUBSTRING, NOT LIKE, etc., and cannot achieve the result. The result is not OK because I need to select just the 8034, the 8035 is excluded by the pattern and the 8036 by direct ref. code exclusion.

Comment: Bernd, I think there is no need of more data. See the products, they are ref. 8034, 8035, 8036. Now in the exlusion table, you have 2 rows, one 8036, which excludes directly this product, and the other is '++5', which, indirectly should exclude the 8035 product. So the final SELECT should just return the 8034. My question is about modifying the SELECT to add the pattern exclusion. It is not a finished SELECT, that is the question I am asking.

Answer (score 1):

At last the SQL was extremely simple:

```
 SELECT * FROM products AS p WHERE id_products NOT IN
 (SELECT id_products FROM exclusions AS e LEFT JOIN
  products AS p ON p.reference = e.reference WHERE p.id_products IS NOT NULL)
 AND id_products NOT IN
 (SELECT id_products FROM exclusions AS e LEFT JOIN
 products AS p ON SUBSTRING(p.reference, -3)
 LIKE REPLACE(pattern, '+', '%')
 WHERE id_products IS NOT NULL) ORDER BY p.reference ASC
```

Comment: Don't use `not in`. Use `not exists`. .... `not in` produces unexpected results when the data on the ( in me ) part contains a null. It is horrible practice and best to remove it from your tool chest until you become a pro at sql.